# Magento Multi-store E-mail Templates

Tags: magento

I've got a multistore setup (shop A and B) with shared e-mail templates. In these templates, I reference custom variables that are differentiated over A and B.

```
Shop A ==\                           /==> Custom Var (version A)
          >==>  E-mail Template X ==<
Shop B ==/                           \==> Custom Var (version B)
```

This works pretty well, except for 1 issue: when I create an account through the admin for shop B, I cannot get the password reminder to be of shop B. Sending this user a new password will always send out as shop A.

Mind that the welcome mail that gets sent, *is* the correct one (B) but I guess only because you select the sending shop from the Create Account screen.

I do realize that the account is marked as having been created by Admin instead of Shop B as opposed to when one would have registered through Shop B. I can imagine this could contribute to the problem, but still, I'd really like to find a way to:

1. Create an account for Shop B through the admin
2. Have the password reminders sent in Shop B-style

---

*Edit: the following question is related in the sense that is talks about associating a user with a shop from the admin: [How can I change a customer store_id in Magento or set the "created_from" attribute when creating a new customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424423/how-can-i-change-a-customer-store-id-in-magento-or-set-the-created-from-attrib)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that by default, it's just impossible to create an account from the admin that's linked to a specific store. I did find a way though, by listening to adminhtml_customer_prepare_save and abusing the "send from" in the Account creation form.

Here's a module that I whipped up for it:

etc\config.xml:

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Company_AccountPerStore>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </Company_AccountPerStore>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <accountperstore>
        <class>Company_AccountPerStore_Model</class>
      </accountperstore>
    </models>
  </global>
  <adminhtml>
    <events>
      <adminhtml_customer_prepare_save>
        <observers>
          <accountperstore_observer>
            <class>Company_AccountPerStore_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>customerPrepareSave</method>
          </accountperstore_observer>
        </observers>
      </adminhtml_customer_prepare_save>
    </events>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Model\Observer.php:

```
class Company_AccountPerStore_Model_Observer extends Varien_Object
{
  public function customerPrepareSave($observer)
  {
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

    if (!$customer->hasStoreId() && $customer->hasData('sendemail_store_id')) {
      $customer->setStoreId($customer->getData('sendemail_store_id'));
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you won't be able to detect that the account was created with the admin anymore.